# Facebook graph API returns false for existing and public event

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

There is a public Facebook event, for example: http://www.facebook.com/events/197276753679964/
I want to get information about this event using Facebook graph API.
I'm using this query url: http://graph.facebook.com/197276753679964

Facebook returns "false", but event is existing and public, so what's the problem?

There are a few more events with this annoying behaviour, but other ~95% I can read succesfully using FB graph API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the event is owned by a group or page which is restricted demographically, you can only access that even with the access token of a user who can see the event / page.
(this appears to be the case with the example in this question)

In general (one current bug excepted), 'false' means a privacy check failed

Comment: Igy, thanks for your answer, but I don't think that this is the reason in this case. Even you can try to access my given links and probably you will see that event is public and not restricted demographically, but you will get "false" from graph API. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Yes, I can see events information from API with my access token set, but how do I know whitch privacy restriction is preventing me to see events information through graph API?

Comment: That first event page redirects to Facebook's homepage for me; are you sure that it isn't restricted somehow? if it is, you probably meet whatever restriction is set which is why you can see it

Comment: Then probably you're right. But still, it's quite complicated while we can't see which restriction is hiding an event.