# ID/albums/ doesn't return user IDs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API to get the list of the public photo albums. I get my access token and everything works fine for `me/albums` but when I use another user's ID, it doesn't work. However I can access the user's photo albums using the `photos` link on my browser easily. I have both `user_photos` and `friends_photos` permissions in my app.

What am I doing wrong?

Update:
I have found several questions which had the same problem as mine. However their solution doesn't work for me:

[Facebook Graph API returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011027/facebook-graph-api-returns-false)
[Facebook graph API returns false for existing and public event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181019/facebook-graph-api-returns-false-for-existing-and-public-event)

Comment: 1., is that other user a friend of yours, and 2., do they have their privacy settings set so that apps friends are using are allowed to access their albums/photos?

Comment: 1. It is a random user. The photos are not public but they can be accessed if you are signed in the Facebook. 2. I don't know, since I don't know them.